# Как выполнить OnRender асинхронно?

Tags: c#, wpf, ui, асинхронность

Всем привет.

Создал контрол, производный от `Canvas`. Рисую в нем так:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        base.OnRender(dc);

        if (Map != null)
        {
            if (Map.Count > 0)
            {

                FontFamily family = new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/CSTITCHHD.ttf"), "CrossStitch_TG");
                Brush brush = Brushes.Black;

                foreach (var m in Map)
                {
                    FormattedText text = new FormattedText(m.Key.ToString(),
                        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"),
                        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                        new Typeface(family, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal), 18, brush);

                    var X = m.Value.X + (BlockSize / 2 - text.Width / 2) + Offset;
                    var Y = m.Value.Y + (BlockSize / 2 - text.Height / 2) + Offset;

                    Point p = new Point(X, Y);

                    dc.DrawText(text, p);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

`Map` - это большая коллекция (10000-50000 элементов), заполняется она во `ViewModel` в асинхронном методе. При >20000 вешает UI сильно и долго.

Как быть? Есть ли относительно простой вариант рисовать асинхронно? Уже много чего пробовал, ничего не получается.

Скорость уже не важна, главное чтобы UI не вешало, пусть хоть анимация загрузки в `Canvas` повисит, лишь бы остальная часть не висела.

Answer (score 1):

Процесс рендеринга в WPF и так довольно сложный, в частности, основной этап рисования и без того идет асинхронно - так что вряд ли весь этот алгоритм можно перенести в другой поток напрямую.

Можно попробовать вместо Canvas использовать [DrawingVisual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual(v=vs.110).aspx).

Если простой переход не исправит ситуацию - можно растеризовать векторный рисунок в [RenderTargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) и вывести его в [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.image(v=vs.110).aspx)

Насколько я понимаю, сам процесс растеризации можно провести в отдельном потоке, а в UI-поток передать уже результат (RenderTargetBitmap).

Comment: `Drawing Visual` дает тот же результат. Вероятно слишком большой цикл. `Image` не подходит, тк необходим вектор.

Comment: @Salnik кому необходим-то?

Comment: @Salnik вы правда думаете, что пользователь увидит разницу?

Comment: да. Эта конструкция зумится сильно должна. Принтер тоже "увидит".

Comment: а в другом потоке почему-то  `DrawingVisual` выдавал ошибку, что я пытаюсь передать "не правильный" объект, точно формулировку не помню.

Comment: @Salnik глянул сейчас - да, точно, нельзя его передавать, потому что привязан

Comment: @PavelMayorov: А если сказать ему `Freeze()`?

Comment: @VladD так глубоко я WPF не знаю

Comment: Ну, я думаю, можно попросить ТС проэкспериментировать.

Answer (score 1):

Странно все это. Пока не задашь вопрос, мысли в голову не лезут.

Итак, решение не было найдено. Наткнулся я совсем случайно на одну реализацию, и на ее основе решил проблему.

Что я делал.

Конструктор, контрола, который рисует:

```
public MarkMapper()
{
    _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _timer.Interval = RealizationInterval;
    _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
}
```

При изменению колекции "символов-точка" возвращаю стандартные значения переменных, очищаю `Children` у котрола. Запускаю таймер. По тику, получаю из основной коллекции `Map` куски заданной длины. Затем, как видно, рисую в `Realize()`. Также попутно проверяю, чтобы длина части не выходила за рамки, и заканчивалось рисование.

```
    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Map.Count - _start) < RealizationCountAtTime)
        {
            if ((Map.Count - _start) <= 0) { Stop(); return; }
            else
                _count = Map.Count - _start;
        }

        _bunch = Map.ToList().GetRange(_start, _count);
        _start += _count;
        Realize();
    }
```

Рисую, и добавляю в `Children` как `VisualHost`:

```
    private void Realize()
    {            
        //Тут рисуем с помощью DrawingVisual            

        VisualHost host = new VisualHost()
        {
            Visual = drawing,
            IsHitTestVisible = false
        };

        SetTop(host, 0);
        SetLeft(host, 0);
        Children.Add(host);
    }
```

Результат (100 символов раз в 10мс):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и при увеличении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечно, возможно это костыли и/или индийский код, но другого варианта у меня нет. И получил примерно то, что хотел.

Comment: Да, так тоже можно. Подход несколько устаревший, но рабочий. Основная проблема такого подхода - работающие значения констант (интервала таймера и блока отображения) можно найти только подбором, причем оптимальные значения зависят от железа. Иными словами - на более слабых компах UI все так же будет подвисать, а на более сильных - процессор будет простаивать.

Comment: Не забудьте принять свой ответ через 3 дня.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov я сделал интервал таймера и количество символов за тик как `DepencyProperty`, и теперь их можно вынести в UI или в дизайнер Xaml. Да и программа пишется для своих нужд.

Answer (score 0):

Если не получается с асинхронностью - значит, пора оптимизировать алгоритм.

Для начала, надо пройтись по иерархии родительских элементов до корня, преобразовать их границы в систему координат вашего элемента, пересечь - получив тем самым видимые границы, после чего ограничиться выводом только тех надписей, которые в эти самые границы попадают.

После этого надо исходя из RenderTransform определить текущий уровень масштабирования, после чего отбросить те надписи, которые оказываются слишком мелкими.

Или же вместо отбрасывания следует произвести кластеризацию.

Скорее всего, вам потребуется особая структура данных для быстрого выполнения этих операций.

Comment: Были такие мысли. Но все бы ничего, если бы не одно но. Очень частно, особенно на экранах больше 1280*720, картина отображается целиком или почти целиком. Те получается в практически каждом случае рендерить нужно все. Также для печати нужно будет рендерить все.

Comment: @Salnik что-то не верится, что на лист A4 влезет 20 000 текстовых элементов. В любом случае - при печати можно и подождать

Comment: это не обязательно А4. И не обязательно бумага(PDF). Дело в том, что на печать идет все. Там несколько слоев. Корневой слой идет на печать со всеми вложенными и через `Paginator` уже будет резаться на несколько частей.

Comment: @Salnik  В любом случае - при печати можно и подождать

Comment: согласен. Но как я уже говорил, чаще всего рендерить надо все. Можно и подождать пока рендерится, но чтоб хотябы была загрузка/анимация ожидания, которая не возможна из-за блока. Максимум что я могу - это поменять курсор на это время, но это не выход.